# Can't governments who want to censor Tor just block the directory authorities?

Tags: directory, censorship

Can't governments who want to censor Tor just block the directory authorities? Or does the client reach the directory authorities to fetch the consensus only after building a circuit so that we have {user}<->{guard}<->{middle}<->{exit}<->{directory-authority}?
And if so, how can he make a circuit without the consensus?

Answer (score 2):

When a normal client first starts it fetches the directory information from a directory authority (or a fall-back). Since it does not *know* any relays it has no choice but to fetch them directly. At that point a censor could indeed stop the connection being made. However a censor can also just download the directory information and block all relays, which would include the directory authorities and the fall-backs.

This is why censored users use bridges. A user uses the bridge as a [directory guard](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/125-bridges.txt#n139): they fetch the directory information from the bridge, not directly from the directory authorities or fall-backs. They also fetch it over an encrypted connection, not plain-text to avoid the contents of the directory request being detectable.

Any user who might be censored should be using bridges and preferably also some form of pluggable transport.